# How to iteratively chain IEnumerable.Where() using a for loop?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, ienumerable

Consider the following code (albeit, a little contrived, but it's a major simplification of a real-world program):

```
string[] strings = { "ab", "abcd", "abc", "ac", "b", "abcde", "c", "bc" };
string[] filters = { "a", "b", "c" };

// iteratively apply each filter
IEnumerable<string> filteredStrings = strings.ToArray();
foreach (string filter in filters)
{
    // in my real-world program lots of processing and stuff
    // happens here, hence why i need the enclosing foreach loop

    filteredStrings = filteredStrings.Where(s => s.Contains(filter));
}
```

As you can see, the code iteratively filters an array of strings down to a smaller set of strings. When the for-each loop finishes, `filteredStrings` should be the subset of strings that pass all filters. In this example, that would be:

```
{ "abcd", "abc", "abcde" }
```

However, the output I get is:

```
{ "abcd", "abc", "ac", "abcde", "c", "bc" }
```

It seems to only be filtering out those strings not containing `"c"`, which I presume has something to do with it being the last filter. I guess I must not be chaining `IEnumerable.Where()` in the correct way. What's going on here and how can I get the right output?

And yes, that foreach loop needs to remain intact, as per the comments in my code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The where delegate isn't capturing the local variable in the way you expect. Variable `filter` is changing, and it's using the last result in all of the wheres, because Linq does lazy evaluation.

Copy the iteration variable to a local var, and I believe it will capture the way you expect.

```
foreach (string filter in filters)
{
    string localFilter = filter;
    filteredStrings = filteredStrings.Where(s => s.Contains(localFilter));
}
```

Comment: In C# 5 this will work. In C# 4 it doesn't just like you said. See [Eric Lippert: Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You are using an variable that is modified in your loop : `filter`

Create a copy of it:

```
foreach (string filter in filters)
{
    // in my real-world program lots of processing and stuff
    // happens here, hence why i need the enclosing foreach loop

    string f = filter;
    filteredStrings = filteredStrings.Where(s => s.Contains(f));
}
```